# I would like to allow login to a box with no password for a particular user how do I do that?

Tags: unix, password, passwd

I would like a userid to allow logging into a box without a password.  I am not sure how to accomplish this as changing the password to nothing is not allowed.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On linux, for example, if you changed /etc/shadow in the following way you would accomplish what you want.

Change this:

```
user:$1$xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:14650:0:99999:7:::
```

To:

```
user::14650:0:99999:7:::
```

---

For a better answer however, I would recommend looking into [ssh keys](http://oreilly.com/pub/h/66).